# final causes static behavior somehow

Tags: java, reflection, static, final

I have a code like this:

```
public class App {
    private final String some;
    public App(){
        some = "old";
    }
    public static void main(String... args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        App a = new App();
        a.magic();
        System.out.println(a.some);

    }
    private void magic() throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        Field field = this.getClass().getDeclaredField("some");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
        modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
        modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
        field.set(this, "new");
        String someDuplicate = (String) field.get(this);
        System.out.println(someDuplicate);
    }
}
```

the output from this will be

```
new 
new
```

but if i'll change variable initialization to this:

```
private final String some = "old";
```

the output will be

```
new
old
```

seems like inline initialization causes static-like behavior of final non-static field

I could'n find any dock reference to this behavior, may be there is some logical explanation to this.

By the way this way to init field causes behavior like in constructor init case:

```
{
    some = "old";
}
```

Comment: BTW Making the field non final via reflection doesn't do anything here.

Comment: @PeterLawrey it makes me able to change final field value if it was initialized not inline. Question is about why different initialization causes different behavior

Comment: That's why it was a comment rather than an answer and I can change final fields without doing that trick.

Comment: I read in another post (need to find it) that with constant, the compilation simply replace every variable with the value. In that case, with `final`, `a.some` should always be the same so the compiler can replace `a.some` with `"new"` since this is not based on the constructor. Since your are breaking the rules of the variable definition, the compiler don't care.

Comment: @PeterLawrey i assume that it is not code that acceptable to have in real app, but there is some behavior that I found as interesting

Comment: @VladislavTsvirko If you want to be able to deserialize an object which has final feilds, it is acceptable and all serailization library do this AFAIK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `javac` does constant inlining. When you have a code such as

```
class A {
    final String text = "Hello";

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(new A().text);
    }
}
```

The `javac` can inline the constant as it is known at compile time.  This makes changing the underlying field have no effect on places it has been inlined.

By moving the value to the constructor, it is no longer known at compile time.

Dumping the byte code for the `main` method you can see it doesn't read the field but rather `LDC` loads the constant `"Hello"`

```
  public static varargs main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 5 L0
    GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    NEW A
    DUP
    INVOKESPECIAL A.<init> ()V
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/Object.getClass ()Ljava/lang/Class;
    POP
    LDC "Hello"
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/String;)V
   L1
    LINENUMBER 6 L1
    RETURN
   L2
    LOCALVARIABLE args [Ljava/lang/String; L0 L2 0
    MAXSTACK = 3
    MAXLOCALS = 1
```

What I find interesting is that it still creates the `A` and checks it for null using `.getClass()` so it's optimisation only go so far.

BTW You can work around this without using a constructor/initialisation block with a wrapping method.

```
class A {
    final String text = dynamic("Hello");
    // or final String text = String.valueOf("Hello");

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(new A().text);
    }

    static <T> T dynamic(T t) {
        return t;
    }
}
```

or any expression it can't determine at compile time.

Comment: can I upvote twice for that work around ? I never thought about it even if it seems so simple... nice trick !

Comment: @AxelH the `javac` can determine that `1+2` is `3`. ;) It can also determine that `"Hel" + "lo"` is `"Hello"`

Comment: seems it's about javac ability to analyze code, cause in both cases (inline init or constructor\initializer block) when we set value to final variable we can't change it in future, so it can look like `LDC "value of field"` in all cases, but in this example i can see that it do this stuff only in case of inline init, in other cases i can "break the rules" thru reflection